# How can I convert this SQL query to sequelize?

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

```
SELECT
  "flatNo",
  "buildingId",
  count(*)
FROM "FlatDetails"
WHERE "buildingId"= 'E7EA2771'
GROUP BY
  "flatNo",
  "buildingId"
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

I have tried this tool https://pontaku-tools.com/english/ but it is not giving me the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code. The keywords are [**fn** & **literal**](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html)

```
FlatDetails.findAll({
    attributes: ['flatNo', 'buildingId', [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('*')), 'count']],
    where: {
        buildingId: 'E7EA2771'
    },
    group: ['flatNo', 'buildingId'],
    having: sequelize.literal('count(*) > 1'),
    raw: true,
    logging: true
})
.then(flats => {
    console.log(flats);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: this returns me a set of duplicate entries. Is there a straightforward way to delete the duplicates while retaining exactly one unique row in sequelize?

Comment: i have asked that in a separate question now